# docker issue on mac os

Tags: macos, docker

Currentl i am unable to run docker on my mac anymore.

i keep getting this issue and its stuck i cant even click on anything i have to stop it using the activity monitor every time it comes [image: fatal error]

macOS : Big Sur 11.4

i have tried:

1. reinstall and uninstall
2. restart the device
3. i have no virtual machine so i did uninstall my parallels desktop

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue documented here :
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5037

Based on the comments in the link you can try

> Reset to factory defaults from the troubleshoot menu

> First, I killed the hanging process using top | grep "Docker" then kill . Then, I went to my root folder in Finder, made sure permissions for my user were "Read & Write", and that those permissions were applied to items enclosed.

Hope it helps to dig deeper or solve the issue

Comment: i am unable to "Reset to factory default" or "Diagnose & Feedback" or "Exit" since the application is frozen. i have to kill the process from the activity monitor every time.